# Can we recreate Drupal Website with just the "sites" and "themes" folder?

Tags: php, html, mysql, drupal, drupal-8

I was shared a repo with just sites and themes folder in it.

I was suggested to download drupal, install it, and then try to integrate these two folders into it. Is that possible? Because themes somewhat works with no images to display, but on replacing "site" folder's files, the website breaks.

Is it possible to work with it, if yes, how so?

P.S - I'm new to Drupal. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just want to copy the looks of the site in the repo, the themes folder should be fine. If you take what's in there and add it to what you have, you should be able to install a new theme in the UI. But, it would be convenient if you gave some info about what's in the folders.

The content is accessible from the database. So, if you have a database dump in the repo, there's a chance to get that too.